# Sync University group project changes from GitHub repo to personal server

Tags: php, github, ssh, githooks, git-pull

I'm trying to setup a git development workflow for a group University project built with PHP.

Over the past week, I've been helping each member of the team configure their machines so we are able to collaborate code to the main repository. Each developer is now able to successfully sync code between their machines and the remote repository hosted on GitHub, no matter which OS they're using:

[image]

The next part of setting up our workflow is getting an apache server to pull our changes from the GitHub repository. This is so everyone (even the non coders in the team) can see changes in live time and test our system:

[image]

I discovered a cool feature offered by GitHub called [git hooks](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/). This should easily allow us to integrate such a feature into our workflow. I went ahead to install git on the server, setup SSH keys with GitHub and create a new hook.

I then added this PHP code into the file that the hook calls:

```
<?php 
    $output = shell_exec('git pull origin master 2>&1');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Now if I call this code from an SSH terminal session with `php git_pull_post_hook.php` , the latest changes (from any of the developers in the team) will successfully sync. However, whenever the GitHub hook or anyone else accesses the php file over HTTP, nothing happens.

After hours of googling, each problem has lead to another. I've changed file owner permissions as other threads have suggested, but now this is the error I'm getting from the script output (over HTTP):

```
Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm guessing that `www-data` does not have sufficient privileges to access the SSH key within the root folder of our server, so that's what's causing all of these errors... But the `/var/www/.ssh` directory does in fact exist on the server, so I can't understand what's going wrong here.

Sadly nobody else in the group knows anything about this type of thing, nor are there any good guides for setting up this. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Update:

The guide that VonC posted seems to be a suitable solution for what we need to do. I tried deleting the .ssh folder and following each step exactly as it says in that guide, but now we get the following errors stating that there is a permissions error:

`No directory, logging in with HOME=/`

```
root@xxx:~# mkdir /var/www/.ssh
root@xxx:~# chmod 0700 /var/www/.ssh
root@xxx:~# chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.ssh
root@xxx:~# su - www-data -c "ssh-keygen -t rsa"
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Could not stat /var/www/.ssh: Permission denied
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
open /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa failed: Permission denied.
Saving the key failed: /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.
root@xxx:~# chmod 0600 /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod: cannot access `/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa': No such file or directory
root@xxx:~# chmod 0600 /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod: cannot access `/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

As [in this guide](http://technotes.tumblr.com/post/33867325150/php-hook-script-that-can-git-pull-apc-clear-cache), you might have missed the `/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

```bash
touch /var/www/.ssh/known_hosts
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.ssh/known_hosts
sudo -u www-data ssh github.com
```

This is referenced in this [`webjay/gh_hook.php`](https://gist.github.com/webjay/3915531), but you have a simpler version in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/619858)

```php
<?php

// Use in the "Post-Receive URLs" section of your GitHub repo.

if ( $_POST['payload'] ) {
shell_exec( 'cd /srv/www/git-repo/ && git reset --hard HEAD && git pull' );
}

?>hi
```

Comment: Hi VonC, thank you for your answer. This guide does indeed help us. However, we are still facing permission errors when executing the commands within the guide. I have updated my question with additional information regarding this. We would appreciate it if you are able to help further as you really do seem to know your stuff. Thank you.